Gravity forms expected value error. Dynamix value should be loaded not basic 0,00 EUR
i have gravity forms with the mollie addon in my wordpress project. I'm dynamically loading in content but keep getting the error "Total price: Imported value (525,00 €) does not match the expected value (0.00 €)." I've been stuck on this issue for quite some time.
I'm loading the dynamic content in with ACF PRO. How can i change the the expected value to the right one
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    const formId = 1; // Replace with your form ID
    const priceField = document.getElementById('input_1_42'); // Dynamic price field (hidden input for calculations)
    const startMonthField = document.getElementById('input_1_21'); // Start month field
    const lesmomentenField = document.getElementById('input_1_22'); // Days field
    const tijdstipField = document.getElementById('input_1_28'); // Time field
    const productField = document.getElementById('input_1_43'); // Product selection field

    // Helper function to validate that price is a valid number
    function validatePrice(price) {
        return !isNaN(price) && price >= 0;
    }

    // Disable Gravity Forms auto recalculation while setting dynamic content
    function disableRecalculation() {
        if (typeof gformCalculateTotalPrice === 'function') {
            // Temporarily override Gravity Forms' recalculate function
            gformCalculateTotalPrice = function() {};
        }
    }

    // Restore Gravity Forms recalculation after dynamic price is set
    function restoreRecalculation() {
        if (typeof gformCalculateTotalPrice === 'function') {
            gformCalculateTotalPrice = function(formId) {
                if (typeof gf_apply_rules === 'function') {
                    gf_apply_rules(formId); // Apply conditional logic rules only if available
                }
                // Manually recalculate totals
                gformCalculateTotalPrice(formId);
            };
        }
    }

    // Forcefully recalculate the total price
    function forceRecalculation() {
        if (typeof gformCalculateTotalPrice === 'function') {
            gformCalculateTotalPrice(formId); // Forces recalculation of the total before form submission
            console.log('Recalculating total in Gravity Forms');
        }
    }

    // Forcefully update the price field
    function updatePriceField(price) {
        // Remove readonly attribute, if it exists, to make sure we can update the value
        if (priceField.hasAttribute('readonly')) {
            priceField.removeAttribute('readonly');
        }

        // Update the value attribute and displayed price
        priceField.value = price.toFixed(2); // This updates the hidden input field with the correct value for submission
        priceField.setAttribute('value', price.toFixed(2)); // Forcefully set the value attribute in the DOM

        console.log('Forcefully updated priceField value to:', priceField.value);

        // Trigger Gravity Forms recalculation
        forceRecalculation();

        // Re-trigger change event to update Gravity Forms total
        const event = new Event('change', { bubbles: true });
        priceField.dispatchEvent(event);
    }

    // Set the product price dynamically and trigger recalculation
    function setProductPrice(price, label) {
        if (validatePrice(price) && priceField) {
            // Disable recalculation until price is set
            disableRecalculation();

            // Update the price field
            updatePriceField(price);

            // Update the label of the product field with the price
            updateProductLabelWithPrice(label, price);

            // Restore Gravity Forms recalculation after price is set
            restoreRecalculation();
        } else {
            console.error('Invalid price value:', price);
        }
    }

    // Function to update the product label with the price
    function updateProductLabelWithPrice(label, price) {
        const selectedOption = productField.querySelector('option:checked');
        if (selectedOption) {
            selectedOption.textContent = `${label} (€${price.toFixed(2)})`; // Update the selected option label with the price
        }
    }

    // Function to update fields dynamically based on course data
    function updateFields(data) {
        // Update the start month field
        if (startMonthField && startMonthField.tagName === 'SELECT' && data.start_maand) {
            startMonthField.innerHTML = ''; // Clear existing options
            const monthOptions = data.start_maand.map(month => {
                return `<option value="${month}">${month}</option>`;
            }).join('');
            startMonthField.innerHTML = monthOptions;
        }

        // Update the days field
        if (lesmomentenField && data.dagen) {
            lesmomentenField.innerHTML = ''; // Clear existing options
            const dayOptions = data.dagen.map(dag => {
                return `<option value="${dag}">${dag}</option>`;
            }).join('');
            lesmomentenField.innerHTML = dayOptions;
        }

        // Update the time blocks field
        if (tijdstipField && data.tijdblokken) {
            tijdstipField.innerHTML = ''; // Clear existing options
            const timeOptions = data.tijdblokken.map(tijdblok => {
                return `<option value="${tijdblok}">${tijdblok}</option>`;
            }).join('');
            tijdstipField.innerHTML = timeOptions;
        }

        // Set the product price (from ACF field, now correctly handled as a number)
        if (data.totaal_prijs) {
            const price = parseFloat(data.totaal_prijs); // Ensure price is formatted correctly as a number
            setProductPrice(price, productField.options[productField.selectedIndex].text); // Set the product price and update label after fetching
        }
    }

    // Event listener for when the input changes
    if (productField) {
        productField.addEventListener('change', function() {
            const post_id = this.value;
            console.log('Selected Post ID:', post_id);

            // Make an AJAX request to fetch course details
            fetch(cursus_ajax.ajax_url, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                },
                body: new URLSearchParams({
                    'action': 'get_cursus_details',
                    'post_id': post_id
                })
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(response => {
                if (response.success) {
                    updateFields(response.data); // Call updateFields to populate the form
                } else {
                    console.error('Error in response:', response.data); 
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('AJAX error:', error);
            });
        });
    } else {
        console.error('Course selection field (#input_1_43) not found.');
    }

    // Ensure Gravity Forms recalculates the total before form submission
    document.addEventListener('gform_pre_submission', function() {
        const dynamicPrice = parseFloat(priceField.value);

        if (dynamicPrice > 0) {
            console.log("Forcing recalculation with dynamic price:", dynamicPrice);
            gformCalculateTotalPrice(formId); // Forces recalculation of total before form submission
        }
    });
});

I've already added in that the value should be changed to the dynamic value. but even then it doesn't clear the error. Can anyone help me out?

Not sure what goes wrong where in that extended code you have shown, but the error message you quoted, appears to contain two different formats - the expected value uses the dot as decimal separator, whereas your value appears to use a comma.
